# Android Gradle Build: Cannot invoke method packagingOptions() on null object

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting below error while trying to rebuild the project.

Error:(34, 0) Cannot invoke method packagingOptions() on null object.

How can I resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after comparing the build.gradle file with the previous working copy, I found the below addition created new issue. Removing the below line solved the issue.

```
compile  'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

However this is of course a temp solution. It will be great if someone can help me find the root cause and find permanent solution.